# Is it possible to alter the layout of the Xcode user interface?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I have quite bad eyesight and have no peripheral vison and am blind in one eye, as a programmer this can be difficult if the interface is not laid out in a way that helps me focus  in a general area. Basically, I can't see all of my screen at the same time, I sit 7" away from the screen and need to move my head about on a 27" monitor to see all of the screen at once.

One thing that would greatly help me is if I could move the object library to the left under the project navigator, and possibly put the assistant editor underneath interface builder instead of next to it. It's much easier for me to focus on things underneath other elements instead of next to as I have better vertical vision than horizontal vision.

I am very much a keyboard shortcut focused person as I also have trouble with my mouse, I tend to lose it a lot, so I much prefer editor tabs, this would help if when clicking a file it does not change the current editor and I would require double clicking to open the file, is this possible?

Coming from NetBeans where I could move interface elements to anywhere I choose I would love to apply this to Xcode, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place Assistant Editor under IB, Go to View menu->Assistant Editor->All Editors stacked vertically.

Unfortunately Apple doesn't seem to show an option to move object library.